# Apache sticky session from response header

Tags: apache2, load-balancing

I have a requirement where I need to route a series of requests to the same member
in a load balancer cluster.

The requests look like this:

1. /server/create-some-id => responds with a unique ID
2. /server/do-something-with-id/{ID}
3. /server/do-something-with-id/{ID}
   ... etc.

The requirement is that requests 2 and on have to be routed to the same balancer
member as request 1. Due to some legacy code, I can't just create a cookie in 
the response of request 1 to use for routing.

I'm wondering if there's an Apache module which is able to SetEnvIf based on either
a response header or the response body, or any other way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible to enable stickyness based on the response headers or body in Apache 2.